# $project does not return the specified fields

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My document structure

[image]

Here is what i am running ....

```
query = self._database.suiteruns.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "name": 1,
            "user": 1,
            "endTime":1,
            "duration": 1,
            "testCases": 1,
            "verdict": 1
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "user": user_id
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$name",
            "count": {
                "$sum": "$name"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$sort": {
             "updatedTime": -1
        }
    }
])
```

**Result after running the above query**

```
[
  {
   u'count': 0, 
   u'_id': u"Minor GC003"
  }
  .
  .
  .
  . some more objects like this(without the fields mentioned in $project)
]
```

*Expected Outcome *

```
[
{
 "verdict": "",
 "testCases" : [{}],
 .
 .
 . (other fields)
}]
```

*I want to group on name field and match by user and expect other fields too which i have mentioned in the $project, but still i do not get the other fields. 
Any help/discussion would be great...*

Comment: Document Structure is not showing in my end, can you ensure whether it is added and showing in your end. The image is not showing on my side

Comment: You mean the image ?

Comment: Or the query does not result anything you mean ?

Comment: I think you should not use `$project` and `$group` together. First you are doing project, then `$group` is overriding the result coming from `$project`. Try removing `$group` from your query, which will work fine.

Comment: I used $group as i wanted to group my results based on updatedTime

Comment: I know. I am telling, if you remove `$projrct` part, it will project as expected. So if you want to project those fields as well, you have to do it through `$group` only.

Comment: Oh , ok... Can you help me write those fields in the group... How do i add those fields in the group ?

Comment: Let me check, if I can help you.Can you add `aggregate` tag in you question, so that some more people can see this question and help you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113588/discussion-between-cafebabe1991-and-titi23).

Comment: Since this is an IO problem, it would be really helpful if you could show us what your expected document output is from a given sample documents.

Comment: @chridam, ok ill add it

Answer (score 0):

You can try following way:-

```
self._database.suiteruns.aggregate(
   [
      {$match : {"user": user_id}},
      { $group : {
           "_id" : "$name", 
           "result": { $push: "$$ROOT" },     
           "count": 
           {
                "$sum": "$name"
           } 
        }
     }
   ]
)
```

Result will be

```
[
  {
    'count': 0, 
    '_id': u"Minor GC003",
    'result':[{
                'name': 'abcd',
                //All the fields of root level
             }]
  }
]
```

Hope this will help. Refer [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) for more info.

Comment: Seems right, let me check and get back at GOD SPEED.

Comment: $push did not work with root, instead i added all my fields in it manually

Comment: $ not allowed in field path names

Comment: What is your mongodb version? Is it below "2.6" ?

Comment: Its 2.6.11 as i see in my terminal

Comment: Can you give the exact query you are trying? Just now I have tried the given query in the answer and it is working fine for me and giving proper result seems. There is some other issue with your query seems.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113595/discussion-between-cafebabe1991-and-titi23).